# Angular velocity from rotation matrix difference

Tags: matrices, physics

I am working on something for a game. I need to calculate the angular velocity, however in my situation I only have access to the previous rotation matrix and the current rotation matrix. My angular velocity is hereby constant between t0 and t1.
I am not very advanced with matrix math, so please go easy on me.
The normal formula for the angular velocity `W(t) = dR(t)/dt * R(t)^-1` can't be used here, since I have discrete values.
Is there a possibility to calculate the angular velocity between timestep t0 and t1 with the given R0 and R1 rotation matrix of an object?